# Sort from Least to Greater Numbers Line by Line from a Text File or a Multiline/Richtexbox

Tags: c#, sorting

I have some files with large amount of combined numbers that need to be sorted. I tried using Excel, however, it does not work properly, as it does not sort some values (very strange). So, I want to accomplish this using C#. I found the code below from another site and works for one line at a time (not multiline textbox). How can it be modified to be used for several lines of numbers, such as the ones that follow, and sorted from left to right (smallest to greatest) or right to left? Or if there is any other better solution or option. It can either read directly from a text file or from a textbox, then show the results in another textbox or save in a new file.

Numbers* list sample:

```
(1) 19 11 7 12 18   
(2) 25 18 15 10 16  
(3) 12 23 1 18 11   
(4) 4 15 2 3 26 
(5) 14 3 10 8 17    
(6) 8 1 26 14 11    
(7) 16 24 4 6 26    
(8) 14 23 13 21 15  
(9) 21 14 12 19 22  
(10) 1 23 12 6 19   
(11) 11 14 1 25 3
```

*Discard the numbers in parenthesis

Code:

```
 int i, j, temp;
            List<string> array=new List<string>();
            List<int> arrayInt = new List<int>();

            array.AddRange(textBox1.Text.Split(' ').Select(txt => txt.Trim()).ToArray());
            arrayInt = array.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList(); //Converting string array to int array

            for (i = 1; i < array.Count(); i++)
            {
                j = i;

                while (j > 0 && arrayInt[j - 1] > arrayInt[j])
                {
                    temp = arrayInt[j];
                    arrayInt[j] = arrayInt[j - 1];
                    arrayInt[j - 1] = temp;
                    j--;
                }

            }

            for (i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
            {                
                textBox2.Text += arrayInt[i] + " ";
            }
```

### Source [Input an array into a textbox and display sorted array using Insertion sorting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6d39378d-3b56-4b3f-bc5c-95b29264d94a/input-an-array-into-a-textbox-and-diplay-sorted-array-using-insertion-sorting?forum=csharpgeneral)

Note: This is for personal learning, not a homework or something like that.

Comment: What output are you expecting from this program? Do you want the lines sorted so that the line that starts with the smallest number comes first? Do you want the numbers in each text line sorted from smallest to largest? Do you want both?

Comment: Split by new line?,

Comment: @Patrick Tucci, yes. From the least to the greatest (greatest to smallest is just an option), and each has to stay in its own line.

Comment: If excel isn't sorting there are leading/trailing space or the cells are not formatted properly.  Your code will not work because lines starting with one digit number and two digit number sill not sort correctly.  You will get 1,10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,3,30,31....

Comment: @jdweng, slig_3 provided a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have to sort int values and you're not sure which characters are gonna be input in the text box between values, I would go with something like this:

```
// Split the text box into lines
var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var finalText = string.Empty;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var formattedLine = line;

    // Replace all characters that are not a digit by a space
    var charsToReplace = line.ToCharArray().Where(x => !char.IsDigit(x)).Distinct();
    foreach (var charToReplace in charsToReplace)
    {
        formattedLine = line.Replace(charToReplace, ' ');
    }

    // Replace multiple spaces by single space
    formattedLine = new Regex("[ ]{2,}").Replace(formattedLine, " ").Trim();

    // Split the line at every space, and cast the result to an int
    var intEnumerable = formattedLine.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()));

    // Order the list ascending or descending
    //var orderedListDescending = intEnumerable.OrderByDescending(x => x);
    var orderedList = intEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x);

    // Concatenate each ordered line in a string variable, separated by Environment.NewLine
    finalText += string.Join(" ", orderedList) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It sorts, however, it sorts the whole lines and then convert them in one line. Instead, every line has to be kept in its own position, just sorted.

Comment: I edited my response, this should do the trick. At the end, the finalText variable will contain the sorted numbers, line by line.

Comment: Thanks again, though still produces the same output. If I enter two lines, for example:

`10 26 1 17 21`

`24 4 1 9 12`

It produces one single line: `1 1 4 9 10 12 17 21 24 26`

Comment: It depends on which character is used to change line. This line here var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None); used the Environment.NewLine character to detect a new line. If another character is used, you can just change this.

Comment: I think we got it! Sorry, I took the liberty to change it in your answer from `Environment.NewLine` to `"\n"`. Thank you very much!